# С++ Программа.Что делать дальше?

Tags: c++

Я новичок и немного не понимаю суть. В общем я написал **программу на с++**(*Например транспонирование матрицы*). Я так понял это уже **программный продукт**, который можно разместить в интернет, для возможности скачивания ее другими пользователями? Можно сделать ей собственную иконку, дизайн и так далее? Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Что такое "собственная иконка" я понял. А что за "дизайн"?

Comment: Способ установки иконки, и правильный способ передачи экзешника другим людям зависят от ОС и компилятора. У вас какие?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну например,чтобы не просто серая консоль,а что-то покрасивее.(Тот же фон к примеру).

Comment: Картинку на фон консоли вы никак не повесите. Цвет букв и цвет фона поменять можно, но как это сделать - зависит от ОС.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну а в целом я идею правильно понимаю?Спасибо!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat   А насчет картинки на консоль и дизайна,я слышал о графической библиотеке Qt для плюсов,разве с ее помощью нельзя что-либо провернуть?

Comment: Конечно, какой-нибудь графической библиотекой можно открыть окно и рисовать в нем что угодно. *"я идею правильно понимаю"* Какую идею?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Понял,спасибо!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "Какую идею? " Идею,связанную с моим вопросом.

Comment: Не понял. *"Я так понял это уже программный продукт, который можно разместить в интернет"* - эту идею? Ну, "программным продуктом" можно даже hello world назвать, это просто слово. "Разместить в интернете" вы можете что угодно.

Comment: На счет иконки и цвета текста/фона - если назовете ОС и компилятор, вам могут подсказать что-то по этому поводу.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Windows10 Pro,Visual Studio(19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы спрашиваете:

> Я так понял это уже программный продукт, который можно разместить в интернет, для возможности скачивания ее другими пользователями?

Я бы ответил так: есть два основных способа далнейшего развития программного продукта: с открытием исходных кодов и с распространением только программы как продукта,который решает задачу и представляет из себя "черный ящик" для пользователя.

И тот, и другой способ распрстранения программы может быть как платным, так и бесплатным.

И тот, и другой способ предполагает каккое то "сопровождение" пограммного продукта.

В случае использования открытых исходников - очень советую внимательно присмотреться к github.com - то есть, в наше время, я воообще не понимаю, как это сайт можно не знать. Фактически, создав там репозиторий - уже можно сказать, что Вы распространяете спрограммный продукт :-)

При разработке своей собственной программы как закрытого продукта - вероятно, тоже есть какие то проверенные способы, но самое простое что приходит в голову - создать сайт своей программы. Ну, или страничку. И посмотреть, какова будет реакция пользователей. Ну а там ... уже природа Вам подскажет, что делать дальше :-)